# Order posts by title and custom field value?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, pre-get-posts

I want to order posts by title, but always show featured posts first. I have the code below to order posts by title. Now I would like to always show posts first that have the metafield 'wiloke_listgo_toggle_highlight' with the value '1'.
How can I accomplish this?

```
/* Order Posts Alphabetically */
function prefix_modify_query_order( $query ) {
  if ( is_main_query() ) {

    $args =  array( 'title' => 'ASC' );

    $query->set( 'orderby', $args );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'prefix_modify_query_order' );
```

Comment: you need to set `orderby` to an array like that `["meta_value" => "ASC", "title" => "ASC"]` and set `meta_key` to `"wiloke_listgo_toggle_highlight"`.

Comment: As @mmm said but just take care because first you are reordering the admin too. and second if the meta_key not exists its won't show the posts at all. you can check if exists or if not exists but it will order the exists first all with 1 first all with 0 after and all the not exists last.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt to help you with solving your problem would be to do something like this :

```
/* Order Posts Alphabetically */
function prefix_modify_query_order( $query ) {
  if ( is_main_query() ) {

    $query->set(
        'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'query_highlight' => array(
                'key'   => 'wiloke_listgo_toggle_highlight',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );

    $query->set(
        'orderby', array( 
            'title' => 'ASC',
            'query_highlight'   => 'ASC',
        )
    );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'prefix_modify_query_order' );
```

Source : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Usage

The code should start ordering posts by title ASC and also take posts with your custom key with value to 1.

Note : Did not test it so I suggest you to comment this if their is any bugs.

Comment: I don’t think this is what he wanted and that it makes much sense even... I think that OP wanted to show posts with 1 first and then rest of them. Your code is showing only the posts with 1 in custom field and then you use that field for sorting (which makes no sense, since all selected posts have the same value in that field)

Comment: My understanding was that he wanted to order posts by title ASC but also by it custom meta based on a specific value.

Comment: And how is your code doing that? If every selected post have `wiloke_listgo_toggle_highlight = 1`, then what's the point to sort by this value? They're all equal, aren't they? ;)

Comment: Indeed. Some one Said that too. I assume the 1 Might be somehting like a true false statement.